# Asana API Sync Error

Tags: asana-api

I currently have a application running that passes data between Asana and Zendesk.

I have webhooks created for all my Project in Asana and all project events are sent to my webhook end point that verifies the request and tries to identify the event and update Zendesk with relevant data depending on the event type (Some events aren't required).

However I have been receiving the following request from the Webhooks just recently:

```
  "events": [
     {
      "action": "sync_error",
      "message": "There was an error with the event queue, which may have resulted in missed events. If you are keeping resources in sync, you may need to manually re-fetch them.",
      "created_at": "2017-05-23T16:29:13.994Z"
    }
  ]
```

Now because I don't poll the API for event updates I react when the events arrive with me, I haven't considered using a Sync key, the docs suggest this is only required when polling for events. Do I need to use one when using Webhooks also?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, you don't need to track a sync key for webhooks - we proactively try to reach out with them when something changes in Asana, and we track the events that haven't yet been delivered across webhooks (essentially, akin to us updating the sync key server-side whenever webhooks have been successfully delivered).

Basically what's happening here is that for some reason, our event queues detect that there's a problem with their internal state. This means that events didn't get recorded, or webhooks didn't get delivered after a long time. Our events and webhooks try to track changes in a best-effort sense, and there are some things that can happen with our production machines that can cause these sorts of issues, like a machine dying at an inopportune time.

Unfortunately, then, the only way to get back to a good state is to do a full scan of the projects you're tracking, which is what is meant by `you may need to manually re-fetch them.` Basically, a robust implementation of syncing Asana to external resources looks like:

- A diff function that, given a particular task and external resource, detects what state is out of date or different between each resource and choose a merge/patch resolution (i.e. "Make Zendesk look like Asana")
- Receiving a webhook runs that diff/patch process for that one task in a "live" fashion.
- Periodically (on script startup, say, or when webhooks/events are missed and you get an error message like this) update all resources that might have been missed by scanning the entire project and do the diff/patch for every task. This is more expensive, but should be significantly more rare.